# Add hamburger icon and make responsive a custom navbar made with div blocks

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the following custom navbar responsive. I created it using only div blocks because it was easier for me to understand, and the code is shorter, simpler, and pure CSS. Here's a link to the Codepen: https://codepen.io/familias/pen/WNYraNy.

Here is the CSS:

```css
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.superior {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.superior a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
}

.superior a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e5633f;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.inferior {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
}

.inferior a {
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.inferior a:hover {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.superior:hover .inferior {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="superior"><a href="#">News</a>
        <div class="inferior">
          <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
          <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="superior"><a href="#">Politics</a>
        <div class="inferior">
          <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
          <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="superior">
        <a href="#">Economy</a>
        <div class="inferior">
          <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
          <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="superior"><a href="#">Culture</a>
        <div class="inferior">
          <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
          <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="superior"><a href="#">Health</a>
        <div class="inferior">
          <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
          <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="superior"><a href="#">Education</a>
        <div class="inferior">
          <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
          <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="superior"><a href="#">Live</a>
        <div class="inferior">
          <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
          <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need is for the menu to display vertically when viewed on a mobile phone. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) to reach your goal

Comment: To use flexbox or grid you have to modify some html and some css, try it and then, if you have errors, post code here

Comment: Change only display:flex to all element isn't the correct way. I'll suggest to read the links in my previous comment to learn how flexbox works

Comment: I made it almost work, it is displaying vertically and not overlapping but it is not hidden from the beginning. Any idea how to hide it until you click on some SHOW MENU button ? Please look at my updated Codepen https://codepen.io/familias/pen/WNYraNy it is the same link from the question but updated what I did until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
 .superior {
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   }
}
```

You can try this, " @media only screen and (max-width: 600px)" means include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true in this case if screen is smaller than 600px. It will create vertically menu and you can add style as you need.

Comment: With this code the menu goes horizontally, now I need to figure out how to make it elastic without overlapping each other

Comment: ok I fixed almost everything. I just need to hide the button so it only opens when you click on some OPEN link/button

Comment: I made it work now, thanks Migo amigo

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using some grid style with a checkbox label for the hamburger menu: Super ugly but just to show what is where.  Note the hover on the menu show the associated `.inferior` but that could be fancier; more just functional here than super pretty just to show how it can be done.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "main main main" "main main main" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 10em 5em 2em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  background-color: #44dd4044;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.wrapper>* {
  /* just to show the contained elements */
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: grid;
  /* notice the 1em and 2em column for the entire header left and right "padding" */
  grid-template-columns: 1em 1fr 1fr auto 2em;
  grid-template-areas: ". logo check hamburger";
  grid-template-rows: 3.5em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.header .logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .menu-btn {
  grid-area: check;
  /* hide or not this is the check that activates the menu via click on hamburger and css */
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-icon {
  grid-area: hamburger;
}

.container-menu {
  /* put the menu where you want and add style */
  background-color: #ffff00;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  display: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.wrapper>main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #d4ebf2;
}

.wrapper>footer {
  grid-column: 1/5;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.container-menu .superior {
  background-color: #00FFFF20;
  color: #808000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.container-menu .superior .main-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00BFFF;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container-menu .superior .main-link:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFF00;
}

.inferior {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: none;
}

.container-menu .superior:hover .inferior {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.above {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: #000000;
}

.superior {
  grid-column: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  /* style and color the svg hamburger as needed */
  border: solid 1px #00000040;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  color: #0000AA40;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrapper>.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.wrapper:has( .header input#menu-btn:checked)>.container-menu.menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10em auto;
  border: solid 1px lime;
}

input#menu-btn:has(+ label.menu-icon) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="above">I am above</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Oh Happy Day Nav</a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
      <svg class="navicon" height="32px" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" fill="currentColor" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2 s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2 S29.104,22,28,22z"/></svg>
      </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container-menu menu">
    <div class="superior"><a class="main-link" href="#">News</a>
      <div class="inferior">
        <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
        <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="superior"><a class="main-link" href="#">Politics</a>
      <div class="inferior">
        <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
        <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="superior"><a class="main-link" href="#">Economy</a>
      <div class="inferior">
        <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
        <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="superior"><a class="main-link" href="#">Culture</a>
      <div class="inferior">
        <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
        <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="superior"><a class="main-link" href="#">Health</a>
      <div class="inferior">
        <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
        <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="superior"><a class="main-link" href="#">Education</a>
      <div class="inferior">
        <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
        <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="superior"><a class="main-link" href="#">Live</a>
      <div class="inferior">
        <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
        <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>Main Content</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```